# Find out if an NSDate is today, yesterday, tomorrow

Tags: iphone, ios, nsdate

With the iOS SDK I need to find an easy and secure way to see if an NSDate is today, yesterday, tomorrow. What I'm looking for is something like this in pseudo code:

```
NSDate *myDate = someDate;
if ([myDate isTomorrow]) {
    NSLog("Tomorrow"); 
}
```

How would you solve it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compare NSDate for Today or Yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893835/compare-nsdate-for-today-or-yesterday)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Check our Erica Sadun's great `NSDate` `extension` class: http://github.com/erica/NSDate-Extensions

There are lots of date comparisons, among them exactly what you need :)

Comment: Found out after playing with this a little that it seems to have some  issues, for example with daylight saving also the dateBysubstractingDays isn't working. It is a great extension but not always that fail safe.

Comment: For those who will be reading comments: project has been already updated several times so don't worry, everything should work fine.

Comment: Erica's code was *exactly* what I was searching for and a great utility category for NSDate.  Highly recommended.

Comment: This is pretty old, but anyone reading this should consider using a combination of NSCalendar and NSDateComponents instead of using these  interval macros in this utility. NSCalendar takes care of those computations for you and handles edge cases properly.

Answer (score 41):

I understand that this is pretty old, but I want to bring the answer up to date (as I didn't see anyone else post a more up to date answer).

Since iOS 8.0 you have a bunch of functions that you can use for date comparison:

- compareDate:toDate:toUnitGranularity:
- isDate:equalToDate:toUnitGranularity:
- isDate:inSameDayAsDate:
- isDateInToday:
- isDateInTomorrow:
- isDateInWeekend:
- isDateInYesterday:

See below example:

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate new];
NSCalendar* calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

BOOL isToday = [calendar isDateInToday:today];
BOOL isYesterday = [calendar isDateInYesterday:today];
```

isToday will be YES.

isYesterday will be NO, given that we gave it todays date.

See [Apple's Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSCalendar/compareDate:toDate:toUnitGranularity:) for further reading.

Answer (score 4):

Swift 3

```
let isToday = Calendar.current.isDateInToday(yourDate)
```

You can then check the value and proceed accordingly with simply:

```
if isToday {
    //If true, do this
}
```

There are similar functions for tomorrow, weekend, and a few others, for example:

```
let isTomorrow = Calendar.current.isDateInTomorrow(yourDate)
```

[This guide](http://nshipster.com/nscalendar-additions/) has them all in Objective-C and Swift:

[image]