# getting next two weeks from the current date

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am able to display the calendar (dates) of this month in table view and I am highlighting the current date and it is working fine, but now what I want to do is to display next coming 2 weeks from the current date.

I am using the following code to get the dates of the month

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date]; 
NSCalendar *calender = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
days = [calender rangeOfUnit:NSDayCalendarUnit 
                      inUnit:NSMonthCalendarUnit 
                     forDate:today];
```

How to calculate the up coming two weeks from today?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Obtain yesterday with NSDate in objective-c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8135382/obtain-yesterday-with-nsdate-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you can try with:

`NSDate *inTwoWeeks = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:60*60*24*7*2]`

Comment: Best to use `NSCalendar` method: `- (NSDate *)dateByAddingComponents:(NSDateComponents *)comps toDate:(NSDate *)date options:(NSUInteger)opts`, it handles the corner cases.

Answer (score 2):

Check my answer from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8135382/obtain-yestarday-with-nsdate-in-objective-c/8135460#8135460). There you can set value for `daysToAdd` that you want and get the NSDate corresponding.