# Working out "Today" and "Yesterday" from NSDate?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I want to present a date to the user of my app as "Today", "Yesterday" or as a formatted date (i.e. 27/05/2011). Is there a quick way to get "Today" or "Yesterday" based on a given NSDate? If not I can write the code myself, I am just curious if I am overlooking some simpler way than working out remaining hours manually.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you just want to present date to your user, there is an option in `NSDateFormatter` right for that.
`- (void)setDoesRelativeDateFormatting:(BOOL)b`

Take a look at documentation for more information.

Comment: I am using NSDateFormatter and I had not spotted this in the docs, I have to say it does pretty much exactly what I was looking to achieve. Nice find, much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this similar question: [Compare NSDate for Today or Yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893835/compare-nsdate-for-today-or-yesterday/2894076).

You make `NSDate` objects from today and yesterday, and then compare the first 10 characters of their `description` to the `NSDate` you're unsure of.

Comment: This is an interesting method and not one I had thought of, I will have a play and see how it works out for what I am after doing. Much appreciated.

Comment: This works just fine, but setDoesRelativeDateFormatting: (as noted by Evgeniy) does appear to be a little simpler by using the NSDateFormatter.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Date and Time Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtDates.html):

```
NSTimeInterval secondsPerDay = 24 * 60 * 60;
NSDate *today = [[NSDate alloc] init];
NSDate *tomorrow, *yesterday;

tomorrow = [today dateByAddingTimeInterval: secondsPerDay];
yesterday = [today dateByAddingTimeInterval: -secondsPerDay];
[today release];
```

Comment: Thank you, I did see the above but it only gives an NSDate offset by one full day either way from now. It does not compare with an arbitrary reference date.

Comment: @fuzzygoat: You can remove the hours-minutes-seconds by taking the first 10 characters and comparing that to the date you have.